# Convert @Html.Raw to string in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to convert item.text_actualite to a string and then I want to implement substring. But I obtain a part from Html code.
For example: `@{ string h = "<spam>test</spam>"; } @("The h value is: " + h.Substring(0,4))` The result is: `<spam` What I want is get the decoded text and get the substring values.

this is my code:

```
@{ 
string text = @Html.Raw(item.text_actualite).ToString();
}
@if (text.Length > 100)
{
 @(text.Substring(0, 100) + "... ");
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do here... I see no point in trying to get the value from Html.Raw when you have the value already.  Tell us what you are trying to do, not how you're trying to do it.  Are you saying you have HTML in item.text_actualite?  And you want to get the text inside of the html?

Comment: My post is not clear ?! I don't think so. By the way I found the solution thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your content does not contain any < or >, you could remove the surrounding html by using something like:

```
text = text.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```